# Unable to intergrate Dokuwiki with Mantis Bug tracker

Tags: mantis, dokuwiki

I have setup Mantis and trying to intergrate Dokuwiki with mantis.I ve setup but when I click on Wiki menu, it says" Permission Denied"

[image]

If anyone has come across this issue,please let me know of the options to resolve.

Comment: What exactly you've set up? https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:authmantis ?

Comment: Hi Vlad , I Setup Mantis in the WAMP server and  setup Dokuwiki in the same server,  yes the plugin you have mentioned . I downloaded from the site. https://download.dokuwiki.org